# How to add og tags for facebook

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I want to add of tags for `facebook` social media in `Magento 2`. So I do not know by where I can add this from code. Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: u can check in file vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\opengraph/general.phtml it is already set. Is it appearing on the website browser source?

Comment: Do you want to add og tags for all pages ?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh: But this is only working for catalog product detail pages. I want to add on homepage and other cms pages

Comment: @ShashankSharma, Please review my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add one block in `cms_index_index.xml` file in your custom theme and you can add your OG tags there.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <attribute name="prefix" value="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="opengraph.general" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/meta.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can create template here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/meta.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $request = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
?>
<?php if($request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') : ?>
    <meta property="og:type" content="test" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="test" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="test" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="test" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="test" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: this will work for me for home page thanks for code sharing